# In postgres, how can I grant default privileges [SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE] to a role for all newly created views?

Tags: postgresql

Whenever a user creates a new view, only that user has access to the view, and he needs to run an ALTER statement to set the read_write role as the owner of the view, in order for the rest of the members of that role to be able to recreate the view (among other things).

I want members of the read_write role to have access, by default, to all new views. In this feasible?

The postgres database has a read_write role and a bunch of individual users. All users have the read_write role (set to inherit), which has SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE privs on ALL tables in schema public.

I've run this SQL below already. Therefore, wenever a new table is created, members of the read_write role have default access to them.

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO read_write_as;
```

Comment: So do views per [ALTER DEFAULT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html): *Currently, only the privileges for schemas, tables (including views and foreign tables), ... can be altered.*

Comment: Note that that only works for views created by the user that ran that `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` command.